# BIGDECIMAL WITHOUT THE EXPONENTIAL FORMAT -->0.0000 from DATABASE being converted to 0E-4 in .txt file

Tags: java, db2, decimal

I have to get value from a DB2 database and put it in a  `.txt` file.
The value of a column is `0.0000`
but in the `.txt` file it is coming as `0E-4`.

When I take the value from the database, I put it in `String` datatype and then write it into a file.

How do i print `0.0000` in my `.txt` file?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: `0.0000` will never be printed as `E-4`  My guess is that `0.0001` is being printed as `1E-4` as you are not specifying a format.

Comment: You may solve this issue by using `String.format()` with a precision specifier, such as `String.format("%.4f", <value>)`

Comment: StringBuffer X= new StringBuffer();
price_from_db = (String) transactionRow.get("price");
X.append(price_from_db);

fileWriter = new FileWriter(FILENAME);
bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
bufferedWriter.write(X.toString());


Value of price_from_db=0.0000

but in file it shows as E-4

Comment: Sorry,it prints as 0E-4.

Comment: Don't get it from the db as a string - get it as a `BigDecimal`.  Leave formatting/converting to where you actually need it (ie, on storage to the file).

Answer (score 1):

Use `DecimalFormat`

Example :

```
double value = 123456789.6666;
System.out.println(value);

DecimalFormat formatter_1 = new DecimalFormat("#,###.0000");
String stValue = formatter_1.format(value);
System.out.println(stValue);

DecimalFormat formatter_2 = new DecimalFormat("###.0000");
stValue = formatter_2.format(value);
System.out.println(stValue);
```

Output :

```
1.234567896666E8
123,456,789.6666
123456789.6666
```

Comment: `DECIMAL`/`NUMERIC` in RDBMSs actually maps to `BigDecimal`, not `double`.  Although you probably won't have problems if you're just _printing_ it at that precision...  Still, outputting it this way (ie, not getting it from the db as a string) is the best way in general.

Answer (score 0):

If `price_from_db column` declared as decimal(0,4), if there is no value in the database, it will consider `0.0000` by default.

Comment: **maybe**.  It depends on what the column default has been defined as, if the column is nullable...

Answer (score 0):

```
Bigdecimal price;
```

if this value comes from DB as exponetial format say `0E-11`

we can use `price.toPlainString()` in our java code to get the value like `0.00000000000`

Worked for me !!